# Retrieving SharePoint Item ID - Powershell

Tags: document-library, powershell, file

I am creating a script that looks through our WebApp and gets all Site Collections, Sub-Sites and list all the documents with certain pieces of information regarding each item. I have to retrieve items within the folders of each Library which lead me to use a recursive method. However when I use the method I am unsure of how to return the ID of the item (Not GUID). So far anything I have tried has returned a null value. The method I am using is shown below:

```
Function GetFiles($folder)
{ 
  Write-Host "+"$folder.Name
  foreach($file in $folder.Files)
  {
  Write-Host "`t" $file.Name
  }

  # Use recursion to loop through all subfolders.
  foreach ($subFolder in $folder.SubFolders)
  {
  Write-Host "`t" -NoNewline
  GetFiles($Subfolder)
  }
}
```

If anyone would know how to return the ID of the file that would great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the ID of the item for the corresponding file, you may simply try:

```
$file.Item.ID
```

Comment: Just tried what you suggested and it works perfect. Thanks for your help!